# Unable to remove commit from GitHub Enterprise Network Graph

Tags: networking, github, graph, commit, github-enterprise

In the process of tidying up one of our github enterprise repos (Github Enterprise Version: 2.3.9).

I have come across two commits in our Network graph (Graphs -> Network)

Outline below.

[image: Orphaned commit in Github enterprise]
These changes have made it into our 'develop' branch via pull request. However the branch that these commits came in on, is not restorable and there is no branch label or tag showing.

How do I go about removing this apparent orphaned commit from the Network graph? As currently it looks like there is a branch with work that has not been merged in.

Comment: I think you have removed from local and not sync with remote. Try git remote prune origin

Comment: I had tried running prune but had no luck in getting to remove from network graph. This commit was pushed by somebody else. Is this something that will need be run directly on the github enterprise instance?

Comment: @DanH were you able to resolve this?